# Unable to add more than one Layout within a layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am creating an application in android which supports Horizontal and vertical scrolling. I have placed a ***ViewGroup as base***. I have ***loaded a Vertical Scroll Bar*** (extended from FrameLayout) inside the view group. The ***vertical scroll bar contains a Horizontal scroll bar***(derived from FrameLayout) as its child. My idea is to **add a LinearLayout within the HorizontalScrollbar** so that I can add more than one child linearly. However I **could not add more than one LinearLayout** within the Layout that I have added inside the HorizontalScrollBar.
[image: loading one LinearLayout within the Layout present inside the Horizontal scroll Bar.]

[image: Error when Loading more than one LinearLayout within the layout present inside the Horizontal Scroll Bar]

I tried this way. This is my code:

```
     private VScrollViewer Vscroll;
    //VScrollViewer is a class extended from android.widget.ScrollView

    public AndroidGrid(Context paramContext)
    {
        super(paramContext);
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        Vscroll = new VScrollViewer(getContext());
        LinearLayout lr=new LinearLayout(getContext());
        LinearLayout lr1=new LinearLayout(getContext());
        LinearLayout lr2=new LinearLayout(getContext());
        lr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lr1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lr2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lr.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        LinearLayout hlr= new LinearLayout(getContext());
        hlr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for(int i = 20; i < 550; i+=20){
            TextView myText = new TextView(getContext());
            myText.setY(i*3);
            myText.setText("HELLLLLOOOO");
            lr.addView(myText);
            lr1.addView(myText);
            lr2.addView(myText);
        }
        hlr.addView(lr);
        hlr.addView(lr1);
        hlr.addView(lr2);
        Vscroll.container.addView(hlr);
        addView(Vscroll);
    }
```

---

Error Log:

```
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): Process: com.example.baseexample, PID: 18425
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.baseexample/com.example.baseexample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.baseexample.AndroidGrid
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.baseexample.AndroidGrid
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at com.example.baseexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    ... 11 more
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    ... 22 more
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3564)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3417)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3362)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3338)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at com.example.baseexample.AndroidGrid.init(AndroidGrid.java:55)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    at com.example.baseexample.AndroidGrid.<init>(AndroidGrid.java:28)
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425):    ... 25 more
```

---

Can anyone suggest me way to add the LinearLayout lr1 and lr2 inside the LinearLayout hlr?

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: Scrollable view can not contain Scrollable child.

Answer (score 2):

Logcat says:

```
11-12 10:04:57.031: E/AndroidRuntime(18425): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Issue is in this:

```
for(int i = 20; i < 550; i+=20){
    TextView myText = new TextView(getContext());
    myText.setY(i*3);
    myText.setText("HELLLLLOOOO");
    lr.addView(myText);
    lr1.addView(myText);
    lr2.addView(myText);
}
```

You are trying to add a same TextView to three layouts. You should create a new TextView for each layout as shown below:

```
for(int i = 20; i < 550; i+=20){
    TextView myText1 = new TextView(getContext());
    TextView myText2 = new TextView(getContext());
    TextView myText3 = new TextView(getContext());

    myText1.setText("HELLLLLOOOO text 1");
    myText1.setText("HELLLLLOOOO text 2");
    myText1.setText("HELLLLLOOOO text 3");
    lr.addView(myText1);
    lr1.addView(myText2);
    lr2.addView(myText3);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works for me. But on adding more linear layouts horizontally, am unable to scroll the application horizontally. However I have set the orientation of the LinearLayout inside which am adding the vertical linearlayouts as Horizontal.    [hlr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);]    
MoreOver, the linear layouts are arranged inside the HorizontalScrollView. Can anyone point me what am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't have multiple children inside a scrollview. If you want to acheive the same thing, then just create two ScrollViews in View or two LinearLayouts each containing a ScrollView.

Also you have a Scrollview inside of your HorizontalScrollView. You needn't do that. If you need a HorizontalScrollView then remove the child ScrollView, it will have the same affect.

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

P.S. If this answer helps please mark it as the correct answer.